# Error : buttons[i].addEventListener is not a function

Tags: javascript, for-loop, click, addeventlistener

I have this code in Javascript :

```
const buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');

for (let i in buttons) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        alert(e.target.value); 
    });
}
```

So I have 2 problems :

1. The Console Error : "buttons[i].addEventListener is not a function"
2. I have an alert when I click but without the e.target.value which I was expected to alert the buttons[i].textContent

Comment: `for...in` iterates over object properties, which can cause your `i` to be some non-numerical property name like `length`. `buttons['length']` will not be one of the items in the NodeList hence the error. You probably wanted the [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop which iterates over iterables like the structure returned by `getElementsByName`

Comment: Please try using the [debugging capabilities](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Debugging/Debugging_JavaScript) of your browser. Use the debugger: see what `i` is at each iteration and what `buttons[i]` is as a result, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks, finally my error was to use "for in" instead of "for" (I though it was the same thing). This code works :

```
for (let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        alert(buttons[i].textContent); 
    });
}
```